# Centering series of img elements

Tags: html, css, image, centering

Can't figure how to center these 3 img elements horizontal

HTML

```
<!-- Homepage Content -->
<div id="center">

    <img src="images/homepage/wedding.png"/>
    <img src="images/homepage/wildlife.png"/>
    <img src="images/homepage/portrait.png"/>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#center {
display:inline-block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Fairly simple huh but it doesnt work! [Test page](http://beta.monikanormandphoto.com/)

Comment: Specify div width and try to use margin: 0 auto;

Comment: use `text-align: center` for your `#center`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `text-align: center` for your `#center`

```
<div id="center">

   <img src="images/homepage/wedding.png"/>
   <img src="images/homepage/wildlife.png"/>
   <img src="images/homepage/portrait.png"/>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#center{
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#center img{
  display: inline;
}
```

Check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/89b64pmk/) to see demo.